# String addition with int

Tags: java, string

```
System.out.println(1+2+"3");
System.out.println("1"+2+3);
```

output:-

```
33
123
```

First case is understood but the second case is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are doing + operation in string then is works as append(concatenation).

So in your first case `1+2+"3"` ...  `1+2 =3` but when it perform `3+"3"` java concate 3 into String 3 that is 33.

and in second example `"1"+2+3` ... 2 is append into String "1" that results as `12` and then `"12" + 3` so result is = `123`.

Answer (score 3):

if the left part is `String` then it would invoke `+` operation on string which is `append`(concatenation) , while in number it is summation

Answer (score 2):

`+` is right associative; `"1"+2` results in `"12"`, and adding `3` gives `"123"`.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation happens left to right. First time a string is met all the succeeding values are implicitly cast to string before being added to the expression. So in the first case you have 1+2 = 3, then a string is met and 2 is appended to the string "3". Second case - the string "1" is met and then each int is cast to string before being added to the result accumulated so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you add anything to a string, it will be a string so 1 + "2"(string) is "12"(string).
if you keep on adding to string, you will keep on getting strings "12"(string) + 33 is "1233"(string). 
I think this better justify your question.

Thanks

Kapil Garg

Answer (score 0):

well, mathematical expressions are scanned from right usually.

1. In first case, if you scan from right , u get two int operands(**1** and **2**) and u add it and it comes to be **3** as int when move on further you find one operand(**"3"**) is string so you concatenate it and it comes out to be **33**.
2. In second case, if you scan from right u get one string operand(**"1"**) and you concatenate it with **2** so it comes out to be **12** as string, when you move on you find int(**2**), but this time your first operand(**12**) is string, so again you concatenate it and it comes out to be **123**.

Answer (score 0):

in first case 1+2+"3"
first 1+2 is added and appended with string so output is 33.

but in the second case: "1"+2+3 
first string is appended with 2 so operation of "1"+2 is string, automatically last is ("12"+3) also string.

that is :
1st case:
numeric output + string = string

2nd case:
string + numeric = string

**that is casting to parent class with lower/wrapper data types the final output would be parent class.**

Comment: Thanks Murali for your reply.